# How to get time interval beetween uiimage.image property change and actually image appears from web

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I am using SDWebimage-master image downloader
it takes time to appear an image about to 8 sec.
i want to get notification of image at appear time (not .image property change time)
code:

thumbsize:

```
[imgFull setImageWithURL:thumbURL placeholderImage:nil];
```

fullsize :

```
[imgFull setImageWithURL:fullsizeURL placeholderImage:nil];
```

Comment: you mean after downloading complete?

Comment: yes, after executing source-code line, it takes a few seconds to update from thumb to fullSize. I did't manage any other progressive code.    THANKS !

Comment: `[[SDWebImageManager sharedManager]downloadWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize{} completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished){if (finished){//download Finish.}}];` check finish then execute code whatever you want.

Comment: You should add that as an answer so he can mark it as resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method . it will give you progress in `progress` block and `completed` block will call while you getting image. but you should check `if(finished)` because after finish you can get whole image.

```
[[SDWebImageManager sharedManager]downloadWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]  
                     options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload 
                     progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize
                     {
                       //you can show progress here if you want/
                       //float progress = receivedSize / (float)expectedSize;
                       //[progressview setProgress:MAX(MIN(1, progress), 0) animated:YES];
                     } 
                     completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished)
                     {
                         if (finished)
                         {
                           //download Finish.
                         }
                      }];
```

Hope this will help you.